# Highcharts causing IE to run slowly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I m having almost 30 highcharts in my HTML page, at a time displaying the one selected and hiding the rest. While doing so after selecting a few highcharts I am getting a error message: "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly".
Is it because of too many charts being drawn at the same time ?
Is there any ways by which i can destroy the chart which are hidden and recreate them again when selected.

In the jQuery ready (),
I ve a function drawTrendCharts(), which is used to draw the charts dynamically from JSON data

```
function drawTrendCharts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ /*configurations*/    
            });
        }
    });
}    ​
```

Comment: Why don't you just display less information per page? I mean 30 is a ton of information for a user to read through. Can you not break it up into smaller more easily digestable sections?

Comment: 30 charts on IE ! RIP...
`chart.destroy()` does exist

Comment: It happens when you have a long array and loop thrue it. How about show a button/link which when user clicks it display more 10 charts ? So that you just render 10 charts per time. Or try to display it into pages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried emptying the container each time before the ajax call is made & then removed some looping statements made the script run slowly in ie  .. Thus solved the issue